# max value of list without max() method

Tags: python, list, max

I need to find the max value of a list but I can't use the max() method. How would I go about doing this? I'm just a beginner so I'm sure this is pretty easy to find a workaround, however I'm stumped.

Edit: Forgot to mention that it's python I'm working in.

Comment: Iterate through the list and compare.

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: Is this in a specific programming language or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
max = list[0]
for x in list:
    if x > max:
        max = x
print max
```

In this example, we initialize the max value to the first element. Then we iterate through the list, and if we find a larger value than the current max, we assign that value to max. At the end, we should have the largest value, which we print.

Answer (score 6):

Think about how you would do this manually.

If you had a list like this:

```
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
```

To find the max manually, you would start with the first number, 10, and that would be the max. Then you move to the next number, 6:

```
 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
     ^
```

Is it bigger than 10? No, then move to the next number:

```
 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
        ^

 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
           ^
 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
              ^
 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
                 ^
```

Now we come to a number that IS bigger than our max of 10. So then we move the max point:

```
                 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
                 ^
```

Then continue:

```
                 M
[10, 6, 8, 2, 4, 12, 3]
                     ^
```

The list is finished now, and M points at 12.

Now you just need to code it up!

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework to me, but perhaps some logics can help you out:

when you iterate the list, the point is that you want to know whether the current element is the MAX of all others. This can be solved by keeping the MAX up to the current element (say M*) and do a simple comparison between M* and your current element. Then update M* according to the result of that comparison. At the end of the iteration I think you can figure out where your MAX is.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner in python:

```
max = sorted(my_list)[-1]
```

This puts the list in order from smallest to largest, then takes the final value which is the largest.

Comment: You might want to try that at a console.  (Plus I'm pretty sure that if his teacher forbade using `max`, `sorted` is probably out too.)

Comment: You're probably right, but why not show another way? Thanks for the spot, my only excuse is it's late and post-football here...

Answer (score 1):

Here, we use the reduce function that is available in the built-in module called "functools", essentially "reduce" returns only one value, which in this case, is the maximum of the numbers. So, the main logic here is we return the current number if it's larger than the next number in the list, else we just return the next number if it doesn't satisfy the condition.

```py
from functools import reduce
inp = input("Values separated by spaces: ")
arr = map(int, inp.split())
ans = reduce(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y, arr)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s=[10,11,12,9,10,11]
length = len(s)-1
for i in range(length):
    if s[i] > s[i + 1]:
        s[i], s[i + 1] = s[i + 1], s[i]
print(s[-1]) #12
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hi. I tried to solve this without using python sort(), sorted() or max(). The above code is pretty simple. Checking whether the ith element is greater than the next element, if so its swapped with each other till the len(s)-1(since there is no element to compare after len(s)). Finally the last sorted element is printed. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
def max(a):

    res = a[0]
    for i in a:
        if res < i:
            res = i
    return res

array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

print(max(array))
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235335/735926) from 2014.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this.....

```
my_list = [0, 2, 5, 6, 5, 8, 5, 8, 8]
my_max = [ ]
for list in my_list:
       if list > 7:
       my_max = my_max + [list]
Print(my_max)
```

This should output `[8,8,8]`

Comment: Just remember you have to input a number 1 less than the expected output and your good to go.

Answer (score -2):

```
input_string =input("Enter a list numbers or elements separated by space: ")
userList = input_string.split()

l=list((map(int, userList)))
print(l)

a = (len(l))
temp=0

for i in range(0,a-1):
  if l[i]>l[i+1]:
    c=l[i]
    if c>temp:
       temp=c

  else:
    c= l[i+1]  
    if c>temp:
       temp=c


print(temp)
```